# Sqlalchemy add duplicated record in database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm learning the way how to modularize flask application using blueprints and break database models into multiple files (one per entity)

I encounter a strange issue while building SQLite file and writing initial record for admin account, - SQLAlchemy added two records for one user.

Here is project layout and key files

[image]

runserver.py

```
#import os
from sbsuite import app
from sbsuite.database import init_db, createAdmin

init_db()
createAdmin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

models.py

```
from sbsuite import app
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sbsuite.database import Base
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    email = Column(String(80))
    password = Column(String(50))
    roles = Column(String(50))


# JSON Schema
# should I create Marshmallow instance here?
ma = Marshmallow(app)

class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'password')

user_schema = UserSchema()
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)
```

database.py

```
from sbsuite import app
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

engine = create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'], convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()


from sbsuite.api.models import User, UserSchema
from sbsuite.api.productMdl import Product, ProductSchema

def init_db():
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

def createAdmin():
    print("Create admin user")
    admin = User(name="admin",email="admin@sbsuite.com", password="password", roles = "admin")
    with Session(engine) as session:
        session.add(admin)
        session.commit()
    print("admin user created") # why users added twice?
```

In last snippet after `session.commit()` I check database and see two records for admin user.

Comment: You'll likely want to make `name` and possibly `email` unique. Add `unique=True`, but do remember that this will only change your model in Python, not the existing table schema in the database. After making them unique you will also have to deal with the possible constraint violation exceptions.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä - thank you for the suggestion (I had in mind the simplest record sample), but I can't see how it related to duplicated records issue.

Comment: Having a unique constraint makes it impossible to even insert duplicates. It does not solve your existing data issue, but after you have cleaned up your data and added the constraint (in the database), you will not have the data issue again. Naturally your `createAdmin` must be able to either not even attempt to insert, if the admin exists, or fail gracefully, if a constraint violation is raised.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä thank you for clarification )